# comparison of norms in vector ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Assume I have the following equation
$$ \dot{f}(t) \le A(t)f(t),\quad f(0) = f_0$$
where $f:[0,\infty]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ has **positive** components ($\ge0$), $A:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a lower triangular matrix in which all the elements are bounded and $\le$ means component by component. Consider then $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\dot{g}(t) = A(t) g(t),\quad g(0) = f(0) = f_0$$ is it possible, and under which assumptions, to conclude $$||f(t)||\le||g(t)||$$ in the whole $[0,\infty)$ ?